# Using iOS device as TCP client - no Bonjour

Tags: objective-c, tcp, ios

I'd like to use iOS device as a TCP client, but I can't find an understandable API/guide/sample of how to do that. I tried `SimpleNetworkStreams` and `PictureSharing`, but they are both using Bonjour. I can make UDP connections easily, learned via `UDPEcho`, but I can't find as good sample as `UDPEcho` for TCP. I want a simple example of connecting to a server, and print in the screen all the incoming messages from the server - that's it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the AsyncSocket project?

http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/

It supports TCP and UDP. To find it, I googled "cocoa tcp socket class".

Note:
The project was moved to https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour is just a way to announce services — not a replacement for tcp/udp.

The services still use tcp or udp.

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) makes your life easier.

**edit**
As I mentioned above: tcp is a basic protocol for services, while Bonjour can announce services. So see [this tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/) and dont care about the Bonjour stuff.

May google be with you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid it doesn't help me. I'm searching for a sample TCP connection in objective c, and that's now that..