# connect Iphone with wifi enabled device(Example heater having IP address)

Tags: ios

Hi Can we connect Iphone with wifi enabled device(Example heater having IP address) I have searched a lot but could not find solution there is EA framework but for bluetooth only with Game Kit framework we can connect app to app but not from one APP to non IOS wifi enabled Device having IP Address

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean. That the device is wifi enabled and has an IP address says nothing about the protocols it supports. For example, if the device supports HTTP, you can simply connect to it with Safari. Also, are you developing an app, or are you asking in general how to connect an iOS device to an IP address.

Comment: Thanks for reply I am developing app and my app in which The Ethernet device is working according a Modbus TCP/IP Server device (acting as a slave). 
The server listens on TCP port 502 (fixed). device has fixed IP address  I need to connect this device with my Iphone

Comment: For how to connect an iOS device to TCP servers, see the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800057/using-ios-device-as-tcp-client-no-bonjour

Answer (score 0):

iOS fully supports Bonjour, which GameKit leverages. The External Accessories framework is designed for accessories that are certified iPhone compliant by Apple, which may not be the case for you. Bonjour will work across any device that supports it.

Apple have extensive documentation of Bonjour [available here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000119i), but be aware that it is a lower level protocol and is not necessarily a walk in the park to implement.